# Split string to truncate away the last octet of an IP address

Tags: java

I would like to parse an IP address and get rid of the last octet but I don't know which regular expression to use within Java's String split method.

Example user input: `10.120.10.3`

Needed output: `10.120.10`

I am thinking something like this but need a way to find and split off after the third dot:

```
String[] truncated_IP = user_IP.split("\\.");
```

`truncated_IP[0]` should contain what I am looking for.

Comment: Actually, in your example, shouldn't `truncated_IP[0]` be `"10"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `split()`, use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29):

```
input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Using your example:

```
String input = "10.120.10.3";
System.out.println(input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

```
10.120.10
```

---

If you really want to use `split()`, it can be done using the regex `\.(?=[^.]+$)`:

```
input.split("\\.(?=[^.]+$)")[0]
```

Again, using your example:

```
String input = "10.120.10.3";
System.out.println(input.split("\\.(?=[^.]+$)")[0]);
```

```
10.120.10
```

Comment: Thanks arshhajii for the great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substring` and `lastIndexOf`, like so:

```
user_IP.substring(0, user_IP.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a regex to get you the IPAddress from the string

```
      public void findMe(){
            String regex = "(\\d*[.]){2}\\d";

            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("192.168.1.123");

            if (matcher.find()){
                System.out.print(matcher.group());
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex pattern than should work. It returns the sub classes too, but the first element should always be the Class C subnet.

```
var ip = "10.100.243.10";
var classCRegex = "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]).";

var subIP = ip.match(classCRegex)[0];

console.log(subIP);
```

Result: [10.100.243]

Answer (score 0):

With Split use--
`Code :

```
    String s = "10.11.12.13";

    String sPlit[] =s.split("\\.");

    for(int i = 0; i < sPlit.length; i++){
        System.out.println(sPlit[i]);
    }
```

Output:

10

11

12

13

`
and return a string with all but last.

Comment: How does this not solve the problem. you can return combined string excluding the last index. The original post is on split,

Comment: Well I dont agree.. !!Of course you can do plenty of things.But answering the split part the code works perfectly fine. and down vote was uncalled for.

Comment: I disagree. The OP clearly knows about this approach because he's written it in the question: `String[] truncated_IP = user_IP.split("\\.");`. I don't think this helps him in any way.

Comment: The second '\' was edited later. it was not there in the original question.

Comment: Actually, it was. It just didn't show up because of the markdown formatting. You can check the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19123637/revisions) (click "side-by-side markdown").

Comment: I didn't want to trigger a downvote, I am upvoting so you have at least a 0 : )

Answer (score 0):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 in a polymorphic manner, so it can do this in a more general manner, supporting all potential string formats of IPv4 and IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

This example method will truncate the last segment, which is the last octet in IPv4:

```
static void truncateLastSegment(String str) {
    IPAddress addr = new IPAddressString(str).getAddress();
    IPAddressSection section = addr.getSection(0, addr.getSegmentCount() - 1);
    System.out.println("truncated: " + section);
}
```

Trying this out on your example as well as an IPv6 example:

```
truncateLastSegment("10.120.10.3");
truncateLastSegment("2001:db8:0:1234:0:567:8:1");
```

Output:

```
truncated: 10.120.10
truncated: 2001:db8:0:1234:0:567:8
```